# How do I render a Media Library item by itself?

Tags: sitecore

How do I render a Media Library item image in a sublayout with Sitecore controls?  With a normal content Item that has an "Image" field it's a piece of cake... just use the `sc:Image` or `FieldRenderer` control.  But I have something like this:

```xml
<asp:Repeater ID="rptImages" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <sc:FieldRenderer  ????>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repater>
```

And the code behind:

```cs
rptImages.DataSource = Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems("/sitecore/Media Library/Images/Some Image Folder/*")
rptImages.DataBind();
```

So... what goes in the ItemTemplate?  I'm OK with using the ItemDataBound event to do some manual assignment, but it's unclear to me how to go about that.  I feel like I'm missing something really simple here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK... I had trouble answering this originally because I was thinking about it from the wrong angle.  The key is NOT using Sitecore controls in this scenario.  What you really need to do is just get the URL from the Sitecore API and use standard HTML controls:

```xml
<asp:Repeater ID="rptImages" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptImages_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <img src='<%# Sitecore.StringUtil.EnsurePrefix('/', Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl((Sitecore.Data.Items.Item)Container.DataItem)) %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Above your code will retrieve image path in form of .ashx for example: src="/~/media/Images/Article/Article Thumbnail Images/marketing/marketing-Thepsychology-small.ashx". But If I want to use image src with image extension then how to get it? I want image src like: src="/~/media/Images/Article/Article Thumbnail Images/marketing/marketing-Thepsychology-small.JPG".

Comment: MediaManager.GetMediaUrl() does not control what extension is used.  Look at the Media.RequestExtension setting in your web.config to disable the .ashx naming.

Comment: I left Media.RequestExtension setting empty. Then I compiled whole solution, and uploaded new image to sitecore CMS. And it still return me *.ashx extension

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware it's an old question, however:

You could use the following:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptImages" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <sc:FieldRenderer ID="image" runat="server" FieldName="FieldName" 
              Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Or replace the FieldRenderer with the sc:Image.

Comment: This won't work with Media Library items, which is why I posted the question originally.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wondering the same thing, and I've realized that there's one big difference: FieldRenderer (and sc:Image) are **Field**Renderers... A MediaItem is not a field, but an item. That's where the problem is: we should use Image fields, or as the accepted answer states: use plain html.